# Password prompt in a Expect script

Tags: passwords, expect

When I expect a password prompt and I use *send*, it doesn't work.

This is the string I have to capture:

```
Engine admin password:
```

So, I coded the following:

```
expect -re "Engine admin password:"
send -- "$pass\r"
```

I tried every single combination, and the result is always the same:

```
Engine admin password: myPassword
```

It doesn't go on if press Enter or whatever...

Could you help me, please?

Comment: dont post `expect -d` output as an answer as it's not. and according to the `expect -d` output you did not post your real code since there's no *"Confirm engine admin password"* in your code.

Comment: Ok, I have just delete it. 

I added the whole code and the expect ouput in the original question.
Thanks for your time

Comment: According to the debug message `send: sending "\r" to { exp6 }` your `$pass` is empty. So check the value of `$pass` after `set pass $expect_out(1,string)`.

Comment: `package require Expect` is not necessary since you're using Expect.

Comment: Yes, you're right. I didn't type any password in this example. I've edited the question again and I've added the new output: ""send: sending "pass\r" to { exp6 }""

Comment: I've just updated the "expect -d" output since it wasn't complete. Hope it's useful. Thanks everybody!

Answer (score 0):

SOLVED, although it is not efficient. Thanks everybody.

```
    expect -nocase "Engine admin passwo*"
    interact timeout 1 return
    send "$pass\r"
```